# SSRS Deployment Format Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, reporting-services, reportmanager

I have built a report in Visual Studio and it works correctly and previews fine as show below:-

[image]

However, when I deploy it to Report Manager the layout of my report corrupts as shown below:-

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before?

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Generally it works for IE but layout gets distorted in some browsers

Comment: I am using IE9.  I thought that the distortion happened on earlier browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Index was outside the bounds of the box!  jk

A lot of times when you are using the block if you draw it AFTER you had the expressions or text boxes it will think it's scope is on top.  To fix this you usually select them outside of the box, then put them back in.  Then the box realizes it has 'child' elements instead of just existing as a hovering issue.  I had this issue a lot and that is how I fixed it, I hope that works for you as well.

Another common issue is somehow you are listing lengths or widths outside of your box and they jump out.  Make sure everything fits nice and tidy inside the box.